# Why global search is not working for this PrimeNG table?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG. In particular I am using the PrimeNG **p-table** component and I am finding some problem with Global Search.

This is the component: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table

This is my HTML code related to my table:

```
<p-table #dtEmployee [value]="employeesList$ | async" 
            [(selection)]="selectedEmployees" dataKey="id" styleClass="p-datatable-employees" [rowHover]="true"
            [rows]="10" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]" [loading]="loading"
            [paginator]="true" currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
            [filterDelay]="0" [globalFilterFields]="['name','country.name','representative.name','status']">
            <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                <div class="table-header">
                    Lista impiegati
                    <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                        <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" placeholder="Global Search" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3rem"></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="firstName">Name <p-sortIcon field="firstName"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="socialSecurityCode">Codice fiscale <p-sortIcon field="socialSecurityCode"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="companyEmail">E-mail aziendale <p-sortIcon field="companyEmail"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="companyPhone">Telefono aziendale <p-sortIcon field="companyPhone"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="personalEmail">E-mail personale <p-sortIcon field="personalEmail"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th pSortableColumn="personalPhone">Telefono personale <p-sortIcon field="personalPhone"></p-sortIcon></th>
                   
                    <th style="width: 8rem"></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'firstName', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per nome" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'socialSecurityCode', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per codice fiscale" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'companyEmail', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per e-mail aziendale" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'companyPhone', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per e-mail personale" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'personalEmail', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per telefono aziendale" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dtEmployee.filter($event.target.value, 'personalPhone', 'startsWith')" placeholder="Cerca per tenefono personale" class="p-column-filter">
                    </th>
                    
                    
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-employee>
                <tr class="p-selectable-row">
                    <td>
                        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="employee"></p-tableCheckbox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">Nome</span>
                        {{employee.completeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">Codice fiscale</span>
                        <span class="image-text">{{employee.socialSecurityCode}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">E-mail aziendale</span>
                        <span class="image-text">{{employee.companyEmail}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">Telefono aziendale</span>
                        <span class="image-text">{{employee.companyPhone}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">E-mail personale</span>
                        <span class="image-text">{{employee.personalEmail}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="p-column-title">Telefono personale</span>
                        <span class="image-text">{{employee.personalPhone}}</span>
                    </td>
                    
                    
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <button pButton 
                                type="button" 
                                class="p-button-secondary centered-icon" 
                                icon="pi pi-info-circle"
                                (click)="showEmployeDetailsDialog(employee)">
                        </button>
                        <button pButton type="button" class="p-button-secondary centered-icon" icon="pi pi-cog"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Non sono stati trovati impiegati.</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

It renders this view:

[image]

As you can see the table header contains filters for each fields (these search filters works fine) and the highlighted global search filter field. This is not working. Infact if I try to search something I will always obtain an empty table, searching for a value inside a field infact I am obtaining:

[image]

I obtain the same behavior searching for information inside other fields.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Viral Patel is correct, you are using the example's globalFilterFields. Instead, specify the table fields you want to include in the search:

```
[globalFilterFields]="['firstName','socialSecurityCode','companyEmail','companyPhone','personalEmail','personalPhone']
```

As far as the icon, it does that for me too. I did this to get around it. It puts the icon on the outside of the search box, but it is better than default.

You can do placeholder="cerca dipendenti", instead of placeholder="Global Search" (If google translate is to be trusted).

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <i class="fa fa-search mr-1"></i>
          <input
            type="text"
            pInputText
            size="30"
            placeholder="Search"
            (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')"
          />
</div>
```

Comment: Include the complete solution in you answer. I see that you have relied on other answer for the first part of the question. This is no especially in case the other person removes the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your global serach is not working because you pass wrong fileds inside your [globalFilterFields] property.
globalFilterFields is an array of fields as string to use in global filtering.
So you need to set like below

```
[globalFilterFields]="['firstName','socialSecurityCode','companyEmail','companyPhone','personalEmail','personalPhone']
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon is outside because the following module is not imported.

import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';